# Two international connections from India to Canada via Bangkok and Tokyo

Tags: canada, japan, thailand

I am travelling with an Indian passport from Delhi to Calgary on one ticket. I have a connection in Bangkok (2 hours) and Tokyo (1 hour 15 minutes). I wanted to know if I will need any visa since I have two different connections in Bangkok and Tokyo.

Also, is 1 hour 15 minutes enough in Narita?

Comment: Which airline are you flying with?

Comment: NO,You don't need it.

Comment: Air India from Delhi to Bangkok, ANA from Bangkok to Japan and Air Canada from Tokyo to Calgary. It is basically a Air Canada flight.

Answer (score 1):

One hour and 15 minutes is tight but doable. You don't need to clear customs or Immigration and your bags will be checked through. However, you have to go through security once. ANA arrives Terminal and Air Canada departs Terminal 1. See https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/connect/inter/inter_inter_t1/

It's a legal connection, so if you don't make the flight, they will put you on the next one and put you up in a hotel if needed.

In this case, it may be a good idea to check a bag. If you get snagged in security, the airline has the choice to wait or leave without you. However, they can't take your bag (for security reasons) without you being on board. So they would need to unload it first, which costs time and money. Hence they may be more inclined to just wait until you show up.